# Strange result using of the DBSCAN clustering procedure

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I'm working on task related to clustering task. DBSCAN  fit procedure produces strange result and I cannot understand where is my mistake. I simplified code and left only important part:

```
clusters = pd.read_csv('cl.csv')

def stb_metric(mac1, mac2):
    if mac1[0] == mac2[0]:
        return 0
    print(mac1[0], mac2[0])
    return 1

X = clusters.mac.unique().reshape(-1, 1)
db = DBSCAN(eps = 1, min_samples = 1, metric = stb_metric).fit(X)
```

In 'stb_metric' output I observe non-existent mac1 or mac2. I have attached csv file for testing. Output is following:

```
(8.354702571827299e+18, 2.9454553327798374e+17)
(8.354702571827299e+18, 6.197480706091255e+17)
(8.354702571827299e+18, 2.2314854373712773e+18)
(8.354702571827299e+18, 2.5842000416550815e+18)
(8.354702571827299e+18, 3.525512049236994e+18)
(8.354702571827299e+18, 3.678065423036415e+18)
(8.354702571827299e+18, 5.232482030018176e+18)
(8.354702571827299e+18, 9.212176082078934e+18)
(8.354702571827299e+18, 1.0293104245975763e+19)
(8.354702571827299e+18, 1.2339113289676194e+19)
(8.354702571827299e+18, 1.2848720441363968e+19) etc
```

[Data where reproduced the problem](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vj--GItNL2uBhch6T1oNjdYnhlL0QeVi)

Comment: Have you tried specifying `dtype` in `pd.read_csv`?

Comment: Type no matter - I have done few experiments changing type for mac field....

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the combination you use with a discrete metric and minpts=1 means that you are abusing DBSCAN to detect duplicates. There are much more efficient and smarter ways of doing this...

Now your problem likely is: sklearn.

It tries to be smart, and likely tries to use a ball-tree to accelerate this. Unfortunately, pure python is slow, so these parts are built in Cython, and this ends up forcing your data to be converted into float vectors - because that is the only data type supported by these subroutines.

The workaround is to use `algorithm="brute"`, but the runtime will be O(n²). It will usually be better to use a precomputed distance matrix (if you can afford O(n²) memory) than to use a ufunc distance with sklearn, unfortunately.